# While creating word document from html in c#,header image is taking relative path instead of ambeded object

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I am creating word document from html. follwoing is little code part

```
strBody.Append("<div class='Section1'>                                                                                                                                  " +
                                "    <table id='hrdftrtbl' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>                                                                                       " +
                                "    <tr><td>" +
                                "<div style='mso-element:header' id=h1 >                                                                                                 " +
                                "        <!-- HEADER-tags -->    " +
                                "         <p class='MsoHeader' ><img width='796'  src='" + headerimgpath + "'/></p>  " +
                                "        <!-- end HEADER-tags -->                                                                                                                            " +
                                "        </div>                                                                                                                                              " +
                                "    </td></tr>                                                                                                                                                   " +
                                "    <tr><td>" +
                                "      <div style='mso-element:footer' id=f1>" +
                                "        <!-- FOOTER-tags -->                                                                                                                                " +
                                "        <p class='MsoFooter'>" +
                                "           <img width='796' src='" + footerimgpath + "'/>" +
                                "<!-- end FOOTER-tags -->" +
                                " </p>   " +
                                "       </div>                                                                                                                                                     " +
                                "    </td></tr>                                                                                                                                              " +
                                "    </table>                                                                                                                                                " +
                                "</div>                                                                                                                                                      " +
                                "</body></html>") 

Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword");
Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
Response.Write(strBody);
```

Here headerimgpath  is my localhost relative URL for that image. So once I create word document, header image should be embedded inside word document itself. But some how it is referring to the localhost path, which is being failed on other system.
So how can I attach header image as embedded object?

Comment: For a start, that's not actually a Word document content. It's HTML. If you want to return a full Word document, you need a library (maybe Word) that can create the Word XML files and compress them. Oh, and the code isn't even valid. Maybe showing a correct example that compiles may help?

Comment: Looks more like VB.NET code than C#.

Comment: Yes, I want to create word document from HTML. Also, this is not complete code, the string builder contains more large other values. to reduce complexity, I have just given string for the header and footer stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

I have this question too, so I think that there is no any way.
We can use word content generation dll (bad way, not crosswordversions), or share img in internet and use internet link (not good, internet requared), also you can put your image in strong hierarchy directories and use relative path like  `..\..\dir\img` (I use this, but it has problems with doc moving).